Tufte-book & biblatex: behave like alphabetic but put fullcite in margin
I'm using the tufte-book document class. I would like to have citations working partly as the alphabetic style, and partly as the default behaviour or tufte-book.
More precisely, I would like the bibliography to behave like in the alphabetic style, but on the first citation of some reference inside a chapter, a marginnote is added with the name of the citation, the authors name, the title and the year.
For instance, I would like
\documentclass[a4paper]{tufte-book}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Some chapter}

\cite{Bringhurst2005}
(...)
\cite{Bringhurst2005}

\chapter{Another chapter}

\cite{Bringhurst2005}

\bibliography{sample-handout}  
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} 

\end{document}

to produce the following result: each \cite prints [Bri05]. Next to the first and third \cite command, but not next to the second one, something like "[Bri05] Bringhurst, The Elements of Typography, 2005." should be printed.
I would also like to be able to use postnotes, as in \cite[Theorem 1]{Bringhurst2005}.
From what I understand the \ifentryseen command of biblatex should be helpful to solve my problem, but my attempts have failed so far.
